# Find $\alpha$ such that $y'=\sqrt{1+y^4}-|y|^\alpha$ has global solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find $\alpha$ such that $y'=\sqrt{1+y^4}-|y|^\alpha$ has global solutions?

For example, imposing $y'=0$ for $\alpha=4$ we get that for solutions with starting point in $$[-(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1/4}, +(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1/4}]$$ have global solutions while the others, with a comparison, can be shown to have vertical asymptotes.

In general, I can "see", but I'm not able to carry out all the calculations needed, that when $2\alpha>4$, the equation $y'=0$ has solutions, thus we can find an interval inside which the solutions are global, while outside they are not (how to prove?)

When $\alpha=2$ all the solutions are global, this I can prove by showing that $y'\rightarrow 0 \;(y\rightarrow \infty)$.

When $\alpha<2$ we have $y'\rightarrow \infty \;(y\rightarrow \infty)$ but I can't really conclude something here. My suggestion is that there are no global solutions (maybe all?).

Comment: In general, when we have $x'=|x|^a-|x|^b$ in a differential equation, $a>b$, how do I show that the solutions behave asymptotically like those of $|x|^a$? (Is it true in a first stance?)

Comment: By global you mean over $\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.